# How to pass on app.config settings of a DLL through a xUnit testserver.dll.config?

Tags: c#, dll, xunit, visual-studio-2022

I have the following code structure:

- xUnit tests

  - These use features from `my.dll`

    - The `my.dll` uses a third party `logger.dll`

If I use the `my.dll` outside of xUnit's `testserver.dll`, then I can just add a `my.dll.config` with the following contents:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="Thirdparty.Logger.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <assemblySettings>
    <add key="Hostname" value="127.0.0.1"/>
    <add key="Port" value="1234"/>
  </assemblySettings>
    
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6"/>
  </startup>

  <applicationSettings>
    <Thirdparty.Logger.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="LogPath" serializeAs="String">
        <value>C:\log\dir</value>
      </setting>
    </Thirdparty.Logger.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

And within `my.dll`'s constructor, I can read them like follows, which works just fine.

```cs
AssemblySettings settings = new AssemblySettings();
var host = settings["Hostname"];
var port = settings["Port"];
```

Also the `LogPath` is passed on to `logger.dll`, which is closed source to me, but the `logger.dll` can definitely read the value passed on as `LogPath`.

---

Now, I have been successfully able to pass on the `logger.dll`'s settings through xUnit as well using a `testserver.dll.config` file, which looks like follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="Thirdparty.Logger.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
      <section name="MyDll.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6"/>
  </startup>

  <applicationSettings>
    <Thirdparty.Logger.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="LogPath" serializeAs="String">
        <value>C:\log\dir</value>
      </setting>
    </Thirdparty.Logger.Properties.Settings>
    
    <MyDll.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="Hostname" serializeAs="String">
            <value>127.0.0.1</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="Port" serializeAs="String">
            <value>1234</value>
        </setting>
    </MyDll.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

And also in this case, the `LogPath` is successfully passed on, but the settings for `my.dll.config` are not. The `AssemblySettings` instance is `null`:

```cs
AssemblySettings settings = new AssemblySettings();
// settings == null
```

What am I doing wrong?
`Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().FullName` in the constructor of `AssemblySettings` evaluates to `"MyDll, Version=6.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"`, but the returned instance is `null`.